# How can I access the style property of last element in dynamic nested structure?

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am trying to style a custom dynamic nested "list" structure with borders but I am having trouble getting access to the last elements with sass.

I am using angular to dynamically create the list but in the end the structure is similar to this where there can be any number of parents with children:

```
<div class="parent category">...</div>
<div class="parent category">...</div>
<div class="parent category">
    ...
    <div class="child category">...</div>
    <div class="child category">...</div>
    <div class="child category">...</div>
</div>
<div class="parent category">
    ...
    <div class="child category">...</div>
</div>
```

I tried using sass to access the `&:last-child` and `&:last-of-type` on both the parent and child but that is resulting in only the child categories getting the border bottom.
My category class looks like this:

```
.category {
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid gainsboro;
    border-right: 1px solid gainsboro;
    border-left: 1px solid gainsboro;
}
```

EDIT: This is what my list currently looks like and I just need to get these marked areas covered with a border to match.

[image]

Is there a way to correctly add a border bottom to each of the last elements so that this list looks pretty? Let me know if I am leaving any information out that could be helpful.

Comment: Could this be created with an actual list? `ul` or `ol`? If so that lets you more easily style something like this `li > ul` (list inside a list for children)

Comment: @BryceHowitson Well I tried doing a ul initially but the problem is I am using a drag and drop library that requires the "drop area" to bi within a parent element. So when I have the nested list structure within another top most div container there is huge spacing between the lists. Talking about it now though, couldn't I just remove the weird spacing that happens with css?

Comment: [screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/TNuViRhYb) of what it currently looks like I just need that bottom border to show up on those marked places @BryceHowitson

Comment: that helps! Would you add it to the question? I think you'll get better answers.

Comment: @BryceHowitsonyeah absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your border is on the top and sides of a wrapper element (whatever has the white bg). Add a border all the way around and then add a negative margin to pull everything back up the width of the border.

```css
.parent {
  background:#eee;
}
.content {
  background:#fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  
  /* give everything a border */
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  /*pull top back over previous element up so it doesn't cause double borders */
  margin-top:-1px;
}

.parent > .child {
  margin-left: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Row content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Row content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Row content</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Row content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Row content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Row content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Row content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Row content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Row content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Row content</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Row content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Row content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Row content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="content">Row content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Row content</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Row content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Boom, that did it! Thanks so much for your help Bryce. I had no idea you could do negative margins, very cool. [So pretty!](https://www.screencast.com/t/4qYw7B79V)

Comment: Yeah negative margins are really useful. But a word of warning. It's much easier to pull things up toward the top of the page than the other direction. Especially so in this case since the next element "sits on top" of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
.parent-category>.child-category:last-child {
  color:red;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

I have created a fiddle for you
https://jsfiddle.net/prd5yeot/1/

Comment: This works for the very last element (3 Day 2 Night Fishing in the attached photo) but then the parent elements with children don't have a bottom border. Thanks though!